# VS Code notebook - can I apply schema validation to a code cell in a notebook?

Tags: vscode-extensions

I have a vscode extension which adds json schema validation to files that match specific patterns. I'd now like to include this validation when a code cell is added to a notebook.

So far I've proven that I can treat the cell as json in which case I get all the normal JSON validation etc but not the validation or completion from my schema.  I have also tried creating my own language in the extension and can create cells with that type which would allow me to add custom validators, but then I lose all the JSON features.

Is there a way for me to force validation of a cell's contents against a specific schema, or alternatively, is there a way I can define my own language but get it to pick up all the standard features of the existing JSON support as well as adding schema validation?